# Meteor HTTP.call on server side correct using?

Tags: javascript, meteor, rss

Sorry for my english.
I'm beginner JS developer. I need help with Meteor.
I try to write rss aggregator.
Can you tell me why this code not work correctly for me?
rssContent is always undefined.
But if I try console.log(result.content) inside HTTP.call I see the rss data.
I need to pass rssContent in another function in this file to parsing XML, but I have trouble with HTTP.call

server.js code:

```
var rssSources = ['http://news.yandex.ru/auto.rss'],
parsedRss = [];

var rssContent;

for (var i = 0; i < rssSources.length; i++) {
    HTTP.call('GET', rssSources[i],
        function(error, result) {
            try {
                rssContent = result.content;
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
    );
}

console.log(rssContent);
```

Comment: You are calling it in callback method?

Comment: No. I need get data from rss sources, parse it and put to Mongo on server side. In example below my server.js content.

Comment: I mean you are assigning data into the callback(async) method i.e. non-blocking method.

Answer (score 1):

Your `rssContent` variable is always undefined because you are calling it inside callback(async) non-blocking method. Instead of callback method, you have to use sync(blocking) method. 
I would suggest you, don't assigning value to a global variable, insert data directly it into the database whenever you got a response of your http request.

Blocking Example:-

```
var rssSources = ['http://news.yandex.ru/auto.rss'],
parsedRss = [];
var rssContent = "";
for (var i = 0; i < rssSources.length; i++) {
  var result = Meteor.http.call("GET", rssSources[i]);
  if(result.statusCode == '200' && result.content){
     rssContent += result.content;
  }
}
console.log(rssContent);
```

Non-Blocking Example:-

```
var rssSources = ['http://news.yandex.ru/auto.rss'],

for (var i = 0; i < rssSources.length; i++) {
    HTTP.call('GET', rssSources[i],
        function(error, result) {
            try {
                //HERE INSERT YOUR DATA INTO THE DATABASE.INSTEAD OF ASSIGNING THE VALUE TO GLOBAL VARIABLE.
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
    );
```

}

Comment: I understand the idea. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of running an HTTP request in Meteor. It runs synchronously by default. If you pass a callback, it runs asynchronously instead. In this case, assuming this is server-side code, it's easier to omit the callback and treat it as synchronous (much less headache IMO).

```
var rssContent = [];

for (var i = 0; i < rssSources.length; i++) {
  var result = HTTP.call('GET', rssSources[i]);
  // error handling
  resultContent.push(result); 
}
```

I'm not familiar on handling errors for the synchronous version. You can head [here for more details in their doc](http://docs.meteor.com/#http_call).

Comment: Thank you. I thought about sync method. I have small experience especially in async development but if I have big array of rss sources? If I use sync request, server may be to busy long time until it has processed the entire array? Probably still need to use asynchronous mode? Or am I wrong?